# Magento CE 1.9.1.0 not creating swatch images

Tags: magento-1.9, image

Magento CE 1.9.1.0 is showing broken images (images that don't exist) for the swatches.

system.log shows the following errors:

```
2014-12-29T14:28:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'imagecreatefrompng' not found or invalid function name  in /Users/franciskim/Sites/foobar/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 60
2014-12-29T14:28:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: imagecolortransparent() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given  in /Users/franciskim/Sites/foobar/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 272
2014-12-29T14:28:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given  in /Users/franciskim/Sites/foobar/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 375
2014-12-29T14:28:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'imagepng' not found or invalid function name  in /Users/franciskim/Sites/foobar/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 166
```

I have PHP GD installed and there are no errors in generating other thumbnails/images.

Answer (score 2):

My PHP GD was missing PNG support (Mac OS X Yosemite). The detailed answer on how to enable this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26505558/960201